# C# How do I send a video over HTTP with partial content?

Tags: c#, file, http

I'm currently building a "video server", it has to be able to send videos over HTTP to the client which is using an HTML( tag) website.
I have this video tag on the website:

```
<video src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?>:8080/stream/0c73f95521d163257379e8ed37839e34" autoplay controls muted></video>
```

And this code on my server: (ctx is my HttpListenerContext)

```
string file = Directory.GetFiles(
contentDirectory,
ctx.Request.RawUrl.Substring(("/stream/").Length) + ".*",
SearchOption.AllDirectories)[0];

//Console.Log(ctx.Request.Headers.GetValues("Range")[0]);

byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
ctx.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
```

I have been looking for a method that works but I haven't found any.

Basically what I'm trying to do is send video over HTTP from my C# program to my website (which is hosted on another web server).

**Update:**
I found this answer yesterday but didn't think I worked because I used an HttpListener, when I read it a bit closer I found that he used a TcpListener.
[Handle range requests with HttpListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920607/2989196)

I hope this might help someone else!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tired just returning a [`new FilePathResult(file, "video/mp4");`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult.aspx) for your action result (assuming the file is a mp4 file)

Comment: You're using C# and PHP ?

Comment: The website is hosted on another server but the videos have to be sent from the C# server.